# Prime clasfication by some constructive function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

How to prove or justify the following:

$$ f(g)= \frac1{1-g^2} \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin(\pi \frac gk)}{\pi \frac gk} \cdot \frac 1{1-\frac{g^2}{k^2}}\right).
$$
The above statement can illustrate the following facts:

(1) if $f(g) = 0$, then $g$ is composite number
(2) If $f(g)$ is not equal to $0$, the $g$ is prime number
(3) if $f(1+g) = 0$, then $g$ is prime.

Please justify.

Comment: @martini! Thank you so much for your editing work.

Comment: Note that $1/(1-g^2)$ is redundant

Comment: I am confused. What is $f$? It is given by the formula, then the formula is true by definition. And if not, how is it defined?

Comment: f is given by the formula. of course, formula is true by definition.

Comment: Oh, so it's the facts *after* the formula that you want proved or justified? That was not clear at all.

Comment: For me it seems that in this form, (3) contradicts (1) and (2).

Comment: I assume you meant $k>1,~$ since otherwise the first term of the infinite product is trivially zero. It all boils down to proving that $~\displaystyle\prod_{k=2}^{g-1}\sin\bigg(\pi~\frac gk\bigg)=0~$ for composite values of *g*, which is trivial, since the fraction $g/k$ is an integer for all instances of $k\mid g$.